# Windows system restore and data lost on mysql

Tags: windows-7, mysql, system-recovery

Is it possibile that a system restore in Windows 7 system may have lost some data in mysql tables?
Mysql data is typically stored in *C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data* folder, few days ago my computer had some problem and ask me for a system restore, after this I got a data rollback.
Is it possibile? Exists some way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear which locations System Restore covers but what you describe is quite possible. The simplest way to prevent it is to move your MySQL data elsewhere:

1. Confirm your *datadir* as follows:

   ```
   mysql> select @@datadir;
   +---------------------------------------------+
   | @@datadir                                   |
   +---------------------------------------------+
   | C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\ |
   +---------------------------------------------+
   1 row in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
2. Stop the MySQL Server service.
3. Navigate to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` and open the **my.ini** file in any text editor.
4. Modify the *datadir* line to where you want your MySQL application data to be stored.
5. Now navigate to your old *datadir* and copy and paste the mysql folder into your new location.
6. Restart the MySQL Server service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... my problem now is "Where I want to store mysql data"? I don't know how system restore works, then I don't know where to move mysql data...

Comment: If you save it in `C:\MySQL` for example, or on another partition entirely, System Restore won't touch it. I'd recommend the latter. It's always best to keep user data on a non-system partition so that you can format and reinstall the OS whenever required.

Comment: Is it possibile to change the datadir using the MySQL installer?

Comment: If it allows you to specify the path then I guess the answer's yes. Been a long time so I cannot confirm.

Comment: Unfortunately I experienced a problem like this with system restore also with mysqldata in c:\Mysql I don't know how, but it happened.